# Receiving error "Unauthorized" while accessing IBM speech-to-text service by following example code in IBM Tutorial

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm following example code from [IBM speech-to-text Getting started tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-gettingStarted) to transcribe a "flac" audio file downloaded from the same tutorial. However I receive this error `{"code":401, "error":"Unauthorized"}` upon running the curl command in Windows cmd.

I'm copying apikey and url from IBM speech-to-text service interface. Using dallas server therefore url includes stream.watsonplatform.net. The audio file is in the same directory where curl is being executed therefore just file name is written in the following code snippet without @ and file path

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{Actual Api key}"\
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"\
--data-binary audio-file.flac\
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct. The credentials are probably not correct, please check that the apikey is correct and that it corresponds to the `speech-to-text` service for the Dallas region.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Daniel. I've double checked the credentials and confident that the apikey corresponds to the speech-to-text service. I'm attempting this example code using IBM Lite free plan. Do you see any connection between the error I stated above and using Lite plan? Moreover, is it fine to not prefix file name with @ if the audio file is placed in the bin folder of curl?

Comment: The syntax is the same regardless of whether you are in the lite or standard plan. If I do the `POST` without the `@` prefix then I get a 400 error. A 401 error is completely different, that one is related to credentials. Given that you are in the lite plan, is it possible that you have reached the limit?

Comment: How can I check the status of limit from IBM console?

Comment: I just checked the Dashboard -speech-to-text-service is provisioned

Comment: Finally worked with two changes: removed back slahes from example code and, changed the location of audio file and provided file path to --data-binary parameter with @ prefix. Here's the code that worked.                                  
'curl -X POST -u "apikey:Actual Key" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary @U:\home\Watson\audio-file.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"'

Comment: Finally worked with two changes: removed back slahes from example code, changed the location of audio file and provided file path to --data-binary parameter with @ prefix. Here's the code that worked.                                  
curl -X POST -u "apikey:Actual Key" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary @U:\home\Watson\audio-file.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize" @Daniel Bolanos: Thanks again for taking interest and responding to my question.

Comment: that is great! :)